# Displaying Data from SQL to vb.net listbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to display all the golfer's information from TGolfers into a ListBox. But when I run my code it only displays one golfer's information.

```
Public Class frmGolfers

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click

        Dim strSelect As String = ""
        Dim strName As String = ""
        Dim cmdSelect As OleDb.OleDbCommand ' this will be used for our Select statement
        Dim drSourceTable As OleDb.OleDbDataReader ' this will be where our data is retrieved to
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable ' this is the table we will load from our reader

        ' open the database
        If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

            ' No, warn the user ...
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine & _
                                "The application will now close.",
                                Me.Text + " Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            ' and close the form/application
            Me.Close()

        End If

        ' Build the select statement using PK from name selected
        strSelect = "SELECT * FROM TGolfers "

        ' Retrieve all the records 
        cmdSelect = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelect, m_conAdministrator)
        drSourceTable = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

        ' load the data table from the reader
        dt.Load(drSourceTable)

        ' populate the text boxes with the data
        lbxDisplay.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString & "," & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString &
                           ControlChars.CrLf & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(4).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString)


        ' close the database connection
        CloseDatabaseConnection()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Because you are adding to the Items of the listbox just the first row of the DataTable (Rows(0)) and not the full datatable. You need to write a loop (IE for|foreach|while there are a lot of choices)

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: this is the loop I used, it gave me this error "There is no row at position 0."                                                                                                        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While drSourceTable.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

Comment: Please press the [edit] button and modify your question adding the code used. In comments it is difficult to understand it

Comment: ' loop to get all data from TGolfers table
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While drSourceTable.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        ' load the data table from the reader
        dt.Load(drSourceTable)

        ' populate the text boxes with the data
        lbxDisplay.Items.Add(dt.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString & "," & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString &
        ControlChars.CrLf & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(3).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(4).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(5).ToString & " " & dt.Rows(0).Item(6).ToString)

Comment: sorry, I wasn't able to edit my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading the DataTable start a loop

```
......  
' load the data table from the reader
dt.Load(drSourceTable)

' populate the text boxes with the data
For Each row in dt.Rows
    Dim text = row(1).ToString & ", " & _
               row(2).ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & " " & _ 
               row(3).ToString & " " & _
               row(4).ToString & " " & _ 
               row(5).ToString & " " & _ 
               row(6).ToString
    lbxDisplay.Items.Add(text)
Next
......
```

In this way you loop over each row present in the dt.Rows collection, extract the information needed, build a string and add the string to the ListBox Items collection.

Notice that I have followed your indexing starting from Index = 1 for each column in the DataRow but keep in mind that in NET the array indexing start at index 0 not 1, so the first column of your datarow is at index 0. Change the index in code accordingly to your need. (This means that if you have 6 columns in that table then the indexing should go from 0 to 5, using the index 6 in this scenario gives an Index out of Range exception)

Comment: You just made my day, sir! Thank you very much!